# Translucent navigation and tab bars appearing opaque despite enabling transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to create a translucent tab and navigation bar using my custom colors however nothing I try enables the transparency. I've looked online and most of them say the translucent boolean is set to true by default however even when I set it as well the bars still stay opaque.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true

UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UITabBar.appearance().translucent = true
```

Yes I've also tried using alpha values.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the background colour on the window in applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
application.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```